# What's the token field in the Order response from the Shopify API?

Tags: shopify

When fetching an [order](http://api.shopify.com/order.html) from the Shopify API a field called `token` is included. There's no details for this filed in the documentation page or [the wiki page](http://wiki.shopify.com/Order_%28API%29#Get_a_single_order).

What is this field? Is it a token from a payment processor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is unique identifier for the Order object that is used during checkout. It is not a field from a payment processor.